# Selenium Web Scraping table with "next" button

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I'm looking to get the data from this open source url:

url = "https://data.sfgov.org/Public-Safety/Map-of-Police-Department-Incident-Reports-2018-to-/jq29-s5wp"

There is a table at the bottom of the page that shows 10 results with a page button to load the next 10, I'm looking to scrape all of the pages.

Using selenium I can get the page open, and I can find the button element for next, however whenever I try and click it, I get an error "message: element not interactable"

```
from selenium import webdriver
from seleneium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)
html = driver.page_source.encode("utf-8")

driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "pager-button-next")
```

this is where I get the error? Any clues on how to get the next page to load up would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Pages that present data are often dynamic. That button is likely not in the page until after the page has had time to load and render the data. You'll need to add some kind of waiting. Selenium does have the ability to wait for elements to exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Data is being fed into page via XHR calls to an API. Why don't you just scrape the API endpoint directly?

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://data.sfgov.org/api/id/wg3w-h783.json?$select=*&$order=`:id`+ASC&$limit=999999&$offset=0&$$read_from_nbe=true&$$version=2.1'

headers = {
    'Accept': 'application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/109.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'
}

r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
df = pd.json_normalize(r.json())
print(df)
```

Result in terminal:

```
    incident_datetime   incident_date   incident_time   incident_year   incident_day_of_week    report_datetime row_id  incident_id incident_number cad_number  ... cnn police_district analysis_neighborhood   supervisor_district supervisor_district_2012    latitude    longitude   point.type  point.coordinates   filed_online
0   2023-03-13T11:10:00.000 2023-03-13T00:00:00.000 11:10   2023    Monday  2023-03-13T11:15:00.000 125358704134    1253587 230177425   230721180   ... 24236000    Mission Mission 6   6   37.77034734336754   -122.41374961166352 Point   [-122.41374961166352, 37.77034734336754]    NaN
1   2023-03-13T01:10:00.000 2023-03-13T00:00:00.000 01:10   2023    Monday  2023-03-13T01:10:00.000 125342774000    1253427 230176819   230720109   ... 23960000    Mission Mission 9   9   37.754398420219516  -122.40925335833268 Point   [-122.40925335833268, 37.754398420219516]   NaN
2   2023-03-12T19:00:00.000 2023-03-12T00:00:00.000 19:00   2023    Sunday  2023-03-13T12:59:00.000 125354907025    1253549 230177641   230721558   ... 23411000    Taraval Sunset/Parkside 4   4   37.74595154171792   -122.49470571387094 Point   [-122.49470571387094, 37.74595154171792]    NaN
3   2023-03-13T19:00:00.000 2023-03-13T00:00:00.000 19:00   2023    Monday  2023-03-13T20:35:00.000 125371672000    1253716 230178962   230723136   ... 26592000    Northern    Japantown   5   5   37.78515093922473   -122.43308339913544 Point   [-122.43308339913544, 37.78515093922473]    NaN
4   2023-03-13T13:00:00.000 2023-03-13T00:00:00.000 13:00   2023    Monday  2023-03-13T15:25:00.000 125369207041    1253692 230178069   230722060   ... 24697000    Central Financial District/South Beach  3   3   37.796926429317054  -122.39950750040278 Point   [-122.39950750040278, 37.796926429317054]   NaN
... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...
776076  2023-08-31T22:00:00.000 2023-08-31T00:00:00.000 22:00   2023    Thursday    2023-09-21T09:10:00.000 132144106244    1321441 236184369   NaN ... 21037000    Ingleside   Bernal Heights  9   9   37.739717624128595  -122.40949339489217 Point   [-122.40949339489217, 37.739717624128595]   True
776077  2023-09-16T20:00:00.000 2023-09-16T00:00:00.000 20:00   2023    Saturday    2023-09-22T13:47:00.000 132159804134    1321598 230682474   232652232   ... 20767000    Bayview Bayview Hunters Point   10  10  37.735891248355564  -122.40282498540331 Point   [-122.40282498540331, 37.735891248355564]   NaN
776078  2023-09-22T11:02:00.000 2023-09-22T00:00:00.000 11:02   2023    Friday  2023-09-22T11:02:00.000 132151716704    1321517 230681670   232651262   ... 24291000    Southern    South of Market 6   6   37.77878537156561   -122.41040149389688 Point   [-122.41040149389688, 37.77878537156561]    NaN
776079  2023-09-08T08:15:00.000 2023-09-08T00:00:00.000 08:15   2023    Friday  2023-09-21T23:50:00.000 132138906374    1321389 236184886   NaN ... 24456000    Northern    Hayes Valley    6   5   37.77408497416307   -122.42240711807445 Point   [-122.42240711807445, 37.77408497416307]    True
776080  2023-09-22T19:45:00.000 2023-09-22T00:00:00.000 19:45   2023    Friday  2023-09-22T19:45:00.000 132166406364    1321664 230683240   232653058   ... 34016000    Tenderloin  Financial District/South Beach  6   3   37.784560141211806  -122.40733704162238 Point   [-122.40733704162238, 37.784560141211806]   NaN
776081 rows × 28 columns
```

No need for Selenium overheads in this instance. See [Requests documentation](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/index.html) and [pandas docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_json.html) for more details.

Comment: thanks! wouldn't have thought to look at the networking and see what the page is calling out to to get the data and just go there myself. this is definitely the solution in this case 